# wpf coordinate system

Tags: wpf

I am starting to work with images in WPF and I am using the next pice of code ...

```
                                    <LineSegment Point="100,-100"/>



                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

How ever it seems like the x,y coordinate system is backwards i mean, I learn in math that in the coordinate plane starts at zero at the bottom and goes up higher on the y axis but in WPF it is the reverse. Zero is at the top of the screen and goes up and you go down the y axis

I read about this in a book and in internet but i do not seem to find the logic of this ... any comments why the WPF use this logic?

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it's been convention since the early days of graphical computing to measure coordinates from the top-left. Sure, in maths we generally have the origin in the bottom-left, but then it is from the top-left we read (at least in English and other Western languages).

Comment: mmm Ok so is just a convention, ok .. but ? what are the insigths of that? why messure that way instead of the old math way?, is there somethins wrong with the old convention?

Thanks !!

Comment: Conventions are arbitrary... Also, books have been written with the text starting in the top-left for millenia, long before there was any mathematical convention. Why not follow that instead? Arguably screen grahpics is more closely related to reading than maths.

Comment: Why use the old math way? What technical advantages does it offer you?

Comment: Didn't old CRTs scan starting from the top left?  It think that would set the precident for where (0,0) was measured on electronic screens.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/30840877/Practical-WPF-Graphics-Programming)

Go to the 36th page using control panel of scribd. There is explanation of 2d coordinate system.